# Facebook Ads Insights API reportstats endpoint

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm using `reportstats` edge to download some reports in CSV format. (It probably applies to XLS as well)

What I've noticed:

- headers have different descriptions than the data columns parameters - is there a resource describing the mapping? (eg. `adgroup_id` -> 'Ad ID', `adgroup_name` -> 'Ad Name', `unique_impressions` -> 'Reach'...
- will the order of csv columns be as defined in `data_columns` param?
- ! some columns are not returned in csv format - two I've identified so far are `inline_actions` and `unique_social_clicks` - the column is skipped in csv format but available in json - is it a bug or there is a reason for that?
- general question - does csv format require pagination or I will always get all of the data?
- value mapping - the constant values in csv/xls format have different labels, eg. placement(`desktop_feed` -> 'News Feed on Desktop Computers'), Is there a resource describing all the possible values?
- asynchronous report requests - it happens quite often that although I'm checking the `report_run_id` for `async_percent_completion` the data is still not available when it should . I'm getting a text response `No data available.`. I need to retry and then it's usually available. Is this expected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- different names in API and XLS are intentional; API developers prefer naming consistent with the rest of Ads API, but people using XLS exports are often not developers and prefer human-friendly naming
- you can use export_columns to define the order
- inline_actions/unique_social_clicks - not sure, maybe these might be deprecated
- it will give you all of the data
- I don't think there's public resource for mapping between placement values :-(
- you need to check report_run_id for the job status (field "async_status"), that should work reliable; once it's "Job Completed" you should be able to get the data

Comment: -  different names between API and XLS absolutely make sense but it start to get problematic once you download the data via API and want to show it in a human-friendly way - no mapping is available as far as I know?

-  export_columns - is this really supported? I cannot find any reference in documentation

-  `async_status` - there are two field `sync_status` and `async_percent_completion` - I check for the latter one - I assume that once it's 100 my report should be immediately available - which is not always the case